# How to get Documents and Settings/username/Local Settings/Temp mapped on another drive

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, symbolic-link

I have a very fast SSD secondary drive, which I"d like to use for my temporary files. I have a program I cannot change that I need to run all the time, and which uses

```
Documents and Settings/username/Local Settings/Temp/*
```

as a place where it reads and writes a lot of things from.

Is there a way to map this folder to my fast SSD drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All information you need to do this are in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link),
a faster alternative is to use a [RAM Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the best way to do this is by changing the TEMP and TMP variables: Right-click My Computer, then click Properties. Go to the Advanced tab, then click Environment Variables, near the bottom. Edit both the TEMP and TMP variables to your desired directory.